# Shift+Super+Right keybinding doesn't work work

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I'm trying to use `<Super><Shift>*` to move windows between monitors on Mint 20.1 with Cinnamon 4.8.6, where `*` is `Right`, `Left`, `Up`, or `Down`. All work as expected except `<Super><Shift>Right`, which just never works. Same problem with different monitors and layouts.

The keybindings all appear correctly on the GUI (Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Windows > Inter-monitor), although I strangely cannot assign the shortcut "`<Super><Shift>Right`" here. If I try, I get "`Shift+Super L`" instead (What is `Super L`?)

Running `dconf dump /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/wm/`, I get as expected:

```
[/]
move-to-monitor-down=['<Super><Shift>Down']
move-to-monitor-left=['<Shift><Super>Left']
move-to-monitor-right=['<Super><Shift>Right']
move-to-monitor-up=['<Super><Shift>Up']
```

Also, I just tried `xev`. I don't understand the output, but with `<Super><Shift>` depressed, I get a new `KeymapNotify event` when pressing `Left`, `Up`, and `Down`, but *not* `Right`.

I don't know what else to try (rebooted, etc.) Is it an input problem? (All keys work individually) Or a hidden conflicting keybinding? If so, how do I find it? (*Nothing* happens when I press `<Super><Shift>Right`) TIA

---

EDIT from comments:

- `dconf dump / | grep -i Super | grep -i Right` yields as expected:

```
move-to-monitor-right=['<Super><Shift>Right']
```

- `gsettings list-recursively | grep -i "super" | grep -i "shift" | grep -i "right"` similarly yields (same for up, down, left):

```
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-right ['<Super><Shift>Right']
org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm move-to-monitor-right ['<Super><Shift>Right']
```

Comment: `Super L` is the left hand super key and `Super R` is the one on the right. My first guess would be a conflicting keybinding as you suggested. Try `grep`ing the output of `dconf dump` or search in `dconf-editor`. Anything there?

Comment: Thanks. I guess I don't have a `Super R`. No luck on `dconf dump / | grep` or `dconf-editor` (so far).

Comment: From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169704) I found that `<Super><Shift>*` is set for all 4 cases in both `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings` and `org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm`.

Comment: Hmm. Please add all this to your question. I'm afraid that I'm stumped though, I was expecting there to be a conflict. Did you try something like `dconf dump / | grep -i Super | grep -i Right`?

Comment: Thanks. Possibly related [issue](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/9462) but adjusting fractional scaling (and other settings on "Display" did not help me).

Comment: Update (sorry for spam): randomly it seems, I printed `dconf dump /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/wm/` and saw `move-to-monitor-right=@as []`. But correcting the value did not fix... (ps, does `dconf` have to be "reloaded" or anything after setting new values?)

Comment: Update again: It seems to be a [BIOS issue](https://forums.lenovo.com/topic/findpost/1300/4573854/4594000) (!) I don't want to tinker with BIOS right now but I will post this as the answer if it works.